# Jsoup throws NullPointerException when checking the hasAttribute Method (Android)

Tags: android, android-studio, nullpointerexception, jsoup

I am trying to extract information from website using jsoup in Android Studio. I put conditionals but couldn't avoid app crashes. It throws NullPointerException error. The error code is:

```
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean org.jsoup.nodes.Element.hasAttr(java.lang.String)' on a null object reference.
```

The related part of the code is:

```
// Check if the related selections are not null
if (relatedNewsPage.select("meta[property=og:title]") != null &&
relatedNewsPage.select("meta[property=og:image]") != null &&
relatedNewsPage.select("meta[property=article:modified_time]") != null) {

    // Check if the related selections has desired attribute
    if(relatedNewsPage.selectFirst("meta[property=og:title]").
       hasAttr("content") && 
    relatedNewsPage.selectFirst("meta[property=og:image]").
       hasAttr("content") &&
    relatedNewsPage.selectFirst("meta[property=article:modified_time]").
       hasAttr("content")){

    //Then extract the news' title, imagelink and update time
      String title = relatedNewsPage.selectFirst("meta[property=og:title]").
             attr("content");
      String imageLink = relatedNewsPage.selectFirst("meta[property=og:image]").
             absUrl("content");
      String updateTime =  relatedNewsPage.selectFirst("meta[property=article:modified_time]").
             attr("content");
```

The error is related to the updateTime attribute. Can anybody help?

Comment: did you try replacing `relatedNewsPage.select` with `relatedNewsPage.selectFirst` where you checking null in parent if block ?

Comment: ok, I will try that way but in my logic if it passes the first check than it will have the elements that i want.

Comment: Better to keep all them in sync, either use `select` or `selectFirst` all the places.

Comment: Your welcome !!.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking null check on `select` but while retrieving content back you are calling `selectFirst`.

Change this

```
if (relatedNewsPage.select("meta[property=og:title]") != null &&
relatedNewsPage.select("meta[property=og:image]") != null &&
relatedNewsPage.select("meta[property=article:modified_time]") != null)
```

TO

```
if (relatedNewsPage.selectFirst("meta[property=og:title]") != null &&
relatedNewsPage.selectFirst("meta[property=og:image]") != null &&
relatedNewsPage.selectFirst("meta[property=article:modified_time]") != null)
```